# rPi 4 two screen configuration without the gui

Tags: pi-4, hdmi, config.txt

I tried plugging two screens with different dimentions into this pi4 and the result is a mess.  What is more, I started with PiOS 64 lite, and am running the i3 desktop.  Loving i3, but of course there is no gui for screen configuration. So far there seem to be three paths to explore:

1. edit /boot/cmdline.txt(the official way to set up screens?)

   looking in that, there was nothing that obviously talks of two displays.
2. edit /boot/firmware/config.txt

   I tried this, cut and pasted off the interweb:

```
[hdmi :0]
disable_splash=1
config_hdmi_boost=7;
enable_uart=1
display_rotate=0
startx=1
gpu_mem=128
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt = 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=w1-gpio

[hdmi :1]
disable_splash=1
config_hdmi_boost=7;
enable_uart=1
display_rotate=0
startx=1
gpu_mem=128
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt = 1920 1080 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
enable_uart=1
dtoverlay=w1-gpio
```

But the pi would not boot.

3. set up a script to run xrandr (what the gui does)
   The manual entry didn't really help.

I want to drive a projector from java with one screen, and run i3 desktop on the other screen whenever the other screen is plugged in.  The java code is looking for $DISPLAY (which is ":0" or ":1") running under X11.

In 2023/2024 what is/will be the right way to set up two displays on a pi?

Comment: So I was looking at it the wrong way. The i3 documentation gives a brief introduction to xrandr and I think I should be able to allocate a "workspace"(i3) to an "output" (??) where an output is one of the things listed by xrandr. But xrandr wants to put both my outputs (HDMI-1 and HDMI-2) on "monitor" 1, and HDMI-2 on "monitor" 2.  I tried xrandr documentation to no avail. The rpi gui seems to do this using xrandr some how.

Comment: `The rpi gui seems to do this using xrandr some how` ... that's how Linux usually works ... a GUI controls a CLI program